# Is there any way to play mkv video on all browsers without any plugin installed on client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, mkv

I am using simple HTML5 `<video>` tag. Now chrome is playing `.mkv` videos but in mozilla firefox it is not supported. So, is there something which will solve my all problems related to playing video on web page?

Answer (score 2):

No. If a browser doesn't support a container format or codec, then it doesn't support it and you need something installed to add support for it.

Consider offering your videos in multiple formats, or at least one with wider support.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the easiest solution is to transcode the video and put it in an MP4  container. Matroska has never been a container with a broad audience. If the audio and video streams are already compatible the transcoding should be pretty fast too. e.g. ffmpeg is able to do this:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.mkv -codec copy output.mp4
```